# regex replace space with tab character

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace the space between the first and second column and second and third column with a `\t` only.

```
0101 A 01/13/13
0102 F 04/05/13
0209 C 04/19/13
```

But i am having trouble doing this, it is putting it all in one line and writing out `\t` instead.

```
preg_replace('/(?:^|\s)/', '\t', $text);
```

Its printing it out as so....

```
\t0101\tA\t01/13/13\t\t ....
```

How can i properly get this in the correct format?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `str_replace(' ', "\t", $string)` doesn't work?

Comment: It is funny to watch everyone pounce on the regex questions... :^) So many ways to solve them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is in a strict format like this, why not

```
preg_replace('/\s+(.)\s+/', "\t$1\t", $text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax adjustment - PHP isn't my first language by a long shot :).

Comment: If there is any chance of extra spaces (e.g., different number of leading digits), I think it was "safer" before the edit, with the original \w rather than `.`

Comment: Yeah...I actually didn't notice the `.` until I posted the comment. I'd have left it with `\w`, but if the format is really this consistent, either's fine.

Comment: `.` matches any single character

Answer (score 3):

Just search for a literal space and replace with `\t`... Unless your data vary more than that, none of the `(?:)` is necessary.

Are there other spaces? Are there more columns?

```
preg_replace('/ /',"\t", $text);
```

If I make a test.php file with:

```
<pre>
<?php 
$t="0101 A 01/13/13\n0102 F 04/05/13\n0209 C 04/19/13"; 
printf(preg_replace('/ /',"\t",$t));  
?> </pre>
```

It generates this:

```
0101    A   01/13/13
0102    F   04/05/13
0209    C   04/19/13
```

Comment: This is basically `str_replace(' ', "\t", $text);`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo(preg_replace('/ /','\t','str str')."\n");//use【''】,result is:【str\tstr】,not work.
echo(preg_replace('/ /',"\t",'str str')."\n");//use【""】,result is:【str  str】,it work.
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation!?

Comment: @WernerHenze I do agree, the answer should include any explanation on what exactly the code does and how it solves the problem. Anyhow I do believe, you can formulate this somewhat nicer. For some people this might be offending, even if just slightly.